# Problem with setting data in two TextView using switch case

Tags: android

this is my piece of code:
declaration:

```
int posizionePagina = 1;
```

switch:

```
posizionePagina = posizionePagina + 1;
if(posizionePagina == 3) {
                posizionePagina = 1;
            }
            switch (posizionePagina) {
                case 1:
                    Title.setText("Giocatori:");
                    Title.setText("a"); 
                case 2:
                    Title.setText("Dati:");
                    Title.setText("b"); 
                default:
            }
```

It is strange because sometimes I get the data of case 1 with the title of case 2, I can't see the problem so I'll appreciate your help.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to break the switch case

```
    case 1:
    ..
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use `break;` for Breaking the `case`.